# Fade out splashscreen, fade in webview in android

Tags: android, webview, splash-screen

Am currently using the code below to switch between my splashscreen and my webview. It works fine except that the switch is abrupt and not really elegant. What I want to know is how to make the splash screen fade away when content is loaded and the webview fadein instead?

here is my working code;

```
@Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            //hide loading image
            findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //show webview
            findViewById(R.id.webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this :

```
private ImageView splash;
```

```java
splash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.SplashId);
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebviewId);

        webview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        splash.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        final Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
        fadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        fadeIn.setDuration(1000);
        final Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
        fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        fadeOut.setStartOffset(1000);
        fadeOut.setDuration(1000);
        final AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(false);
        animation.addAnimation(fadeIn);
        animation.addAnimation(fadeOut);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        splash.setAnimation(fadeOut);
        splash.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    splash.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    webview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    webview.setAnimation(fadeIn);
                }
            }, 1600);
        }


});
```

Gone Splash [**FadeOut**] And then, Visible WebView [**FadeIn**] by Animation.
Enjoy :)

Comment: It works well, nice adaptation.